# 2 way syncing from iOS calendar event to our app

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

How we can do 2 way syncing of calendar events in iOS from our application.
For example say ToDo is my app

1. I create an event in ToDo; it's automatically created into calendar app using event kit.
2. I delete an event in ToDo it's automatically deleted form calendar app

Question:

1. If I create an event into calendar can it be created into ToDo also???
2. If I delete a ToDo event form calendar can it be deleted form ToDo app too???

So basically I need two way syncing of events between my app and the iOS native calendar app

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done if you use the Event kit.
Refer the sample code in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)